# Windows Phone: OnManipulationStarted doesn't fire when touching ad control

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, xaml, windows-phone-8

When I try to add Nokia Ad Exchange ad control in my page XAML, the overridden `OnManipulationStarted` event handler doesn't fire when I touch it. It is fired if I touch anything else, but if I touch it specifically, then it doesn't enter in the method code.

Is this a related issue to the control or should I add something else?

Answer (score 0):

It's probably handled by the control, so it doesn't bubble up.
You can use the alternative control.AddHandler method rather than += to add an event handler. It takes a boolean that specifies if you want the event handler called even if it was handled by a sub-element.

Comment: by Adding Handler with regular method to XAML , no thing happen. and when i try to use add handler method i can't find reference to ManipulationStartedEventHandler to attach this manually . could you give me sample line of code to it.